# Nginx upstream configuration

Tags: linux, nginx

I am trying to configure nginx with upstream.

We have 3 machines where we run application server and proxy passing all requests from nginx to application serves.

I used following configuration in nginx:

```
upstream appcluster {
 server host1.example.com:8080 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=300s;
 server host2.example.com:8080 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=300s;
}
```

Now issue is if the request comes to nginx when one server is down due to unknown reasons it's waiting for a long time getting response or sometimes its getting connection timeout.

Can someone suggest me the right configuration to get a response from the appcluster without latency or connection timeout whenever a server won't respond?

Answer (score 0):

Then these can help,  check the [proxy_next_upstream](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpProxyModule#proxy_next_upstream)

These directive determines in what cases the request will be transmitted to the next server.

Your server block should look like for example:

```
server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://appcluster;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_404;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am also tried with 10 sec's and less but facing same issue.